# Code outputs right information but the formatting is incorrect, How do you segment a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
def string2bin(s):
y = []
for x in s:
    q = []
    q.append(str(bin(ord(x))[2:].zfill(8)))
    y.append(q)
return y
```

It is supposed to output:

```
string2bin('abc')
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

But instead outputs:

```
string2bin('abc')
[['01100001'], ['01100010'], ['01100011']]
```

Also how do you segment a string?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to split up the string into a list of ints.

Comment: What's the `9` good for?

Comment: I accidentally put in that 9, its not actually in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to a list of digits.

```
def string2bin(s):
    y = []
    for x in s:
        q = [int(c) for c in (str(bin(ord(x))[2:].fill(8)))]
        y.append(q)
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def string2bin(s):
  return [list(map(int, str(bin(ord(x)))[2:].zfill(8))) for x in s]

print(string2bin('abc'))
```

It produces (up to indentation):

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

You just missed the `map(int, ...)` and `list(...)` part.

Comment: He wants a list of integers, not strings.

Comment: That mostly works, it outputs now [[['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']], [['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']], [['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']]], I just need to get rid of those extra brackets and get rid of the quotation marks around each character to leave it how it is supposed to output in the OP

Comment: @BryantGuerrero What do you mean by "mostly works"? I was hoping that it "just works"?

Comment: @BryantGuerrero I've updated the answer six minutes ago, it now outputs integers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest edit to your code would be to simply change the append from string to list. As you are adding it to a list as a string, because the way ord works you are simply adding the string as a whole, not as individual values.

```
def string2bin(s):
     y = []
     for x in s:
         q = []
         q.append(list(bin(ord(x))[2:].zfill(8)))
         y.append(q)
     return y
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're taking 1 char at a time out of the string then converting it to bin, removing the 0b and then filling in the rest with 0's to keep the length at 8.

The issue is this in turn gives you a string to append, not an array.

Here's my solution, not the most Pythonic but it's easy to read:

```
def string2bin(s):
    y = []
    for x in s:
        q = []
        adjusted = list(str(bin(ord(x)))[2:].zfill(8))
        for num in adjusted:
            q.append(int(num))
        y.append(q)
    return y

print(string2bin('abc'))
```

This outputs exactly what you've requested:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```